# Deleting first item of list

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that will remove the first item from a list. Here's what a have so far...

```
public void removefromlist(int n)
{
    for(n != 0)
        n = n -1
        If(n -1 != 0)
            List.remove(n)
}
```

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).  You need to be far more specific about what help you need.

Comment: You could start with writing valid Java code.  Your compiler could have told you that you have not done so, in much less time than it took you to compose this question.

Comment: Pseudocode is in general fine but for such a simple example I'd surely expect compileable code ..

Comment: Why not? Isn't that the point?

Comment: @StephenR.The question is tagged as Java. If you do not want Java then do not tag Java.

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, so nothing you do to the `head` parameter reference value will affect the caller. In order for caller to get a reference to the new head node, you need to return a reference to the new head node. The method itself makes no sense, so it's impossible for the code in the method to make sense.

Comment: Does `removeFront` belong to a `LinkedList` class that you're coding yourself? Or is it a method from the outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look up how to build a solid for loop.

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) { }

End your statements properly with ';'

And you've probably forgot that aswell, declare all your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea. For the *for* loop, you should have a *current* variable that is traversing through the linked list via

```
current = head
for i:n
    current = current.next
```

Then to set your new head, you would do

```
head = current.next
```

Of course, my code is more pseudo-code, but that is the idea.

And your *for* loop should look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

If your counting to n, it shouldn't matter if you go up or down.